# Proving that the ratio between the radius of a circle and its circumference is a constant

Tags: calculus, pi

I want to prove that given a circle with a radius $R>0$ then its circumference length is a constant independent of $R$ .

For that purpose I have defined the function $$f(x)=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}, x\in[-R,R]$$ and tried to calculate the length of its curve. Since $f$ is differentiable, to do that, I need to solve
$$\ell (f)=\int_{-R}^{R}\sqrt{1+(f'(t))^2}\mathrm{d}t=\int_{-R}^{R}\sqrt{1+R^2-t^2}\mathrm{d}t$$ I thought that the substitution $s=R\cos (s)$ would do the trick but I can't proceed with it. I thank you for any help/hint!

***EDIT:***

I have changed the subject since I'm not interested in the value of the constant but just to prove that it is a constant.

I have 2 questions in mind:

1. Can we define the trigonometric functions with all their properties before knowing that the ratio is a constant? If so, then the substitution $s=R\cos (s)$ is justified.

Otherwise,

2. Can we bound $\int_0^{R} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{R^2-t^2}} $ without using the trig functions? The integrand is clearly unbounded and I wasn't able to find a different approach.

Thanks again.

Comment: Check your expression for $f'(t)$

Comment: shoot!... thanks

Comment: Define $\pi$, please.

Comment: Doesn't matter, I just want to prove it's a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I think you find f' incorrect
now look at the picture that i send
I hope it will useful

Comment: Yup... thanks a lot!

Comment: @khosrotash For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).